# exercise: using several modules and routes

Tags: angular

I'm really lost with routes and modules, I'm sorry if it's a bit tedious but can someone help me see it more clearly, please?

I have a schema like this (I have to follow this schema)

[image]

I created each module and route. However, the display stays white.

[image]

Normally, When the user visualizes the website, he arrives on the portfolio page.

I'm sure my problems are the roads but I don't see where my worries are.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

The file is empty, I don't know what to write?

**dashboard-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

export const ONLINE_ROUTES: Routes = [

{ path: '', 
  component: DashboardComponent,

  children: [

    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: '/dashboard', 
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },

    { path: 'administration', loadChildren: () => import('./views/administration/administration.module').then(m => m.AdministrationModule) }


  ]

}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(ONLINE_ROUTES)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

**dashboard.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard-routing.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { AdministrationComponent } from './views/administration/administration.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent,
    AdministrationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DashboardRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

**administration-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AdministrationComponent } from './administration.component';
import { AccountOpeningComponent } from './views/account-opening/account-opening.component';
import { PortfolioComponent } from './views/portfolio/portfolio.component';

export const ADMINISTRATION_ROUTES: Routes = [

{ path: '', 
  component: AdministrationComponent,

  children: [

    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: '/portfolio', 
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },

    {
      path: 'portfolio',
      component: PortfolioComponent,
    },

    {
      path: 'account-opening',
      component: AccountOpeningComponent,
    },

  ]

}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(ADMINISTRATION_ROUTES)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdministrationRoutingModule { }
```

**administration.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AdministrationComponent } from './administration.component';
import { AdministrationRoutingModule } from './administration-routing.module';
import { PortfolioComponent } from './views/portfolio/portfolio.component';
import { AccountOpeningComponent } from './views/account-opening/account-opening.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AdministrationComponent,
    PortfolioComponent,
    AccountOpeningComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AdministrationRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class AdministrationModule { }
```

**administration.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**portfolio.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { PortfolioComponent } from './portfolio.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PortfolioComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
  ]
})
export class PortfolioModule { }
```

**portfolio.component.html**

```
<div class="home-content container ">
    <h1 class="text-center pt-5 pb-3">Portfolio</h1>
</div>
```

I can share the code with you on Stackblitz, I think it's better.

Here is the link -> https://stackblitz.com/github/mimi1348/prjet

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: May I know what is the issue you are facing? Its not clear from yor question.

Comment: @Vimal Patel: Sorry, I don't understand why nothing is displayed

Comment: If you are using routing to navigate, then you need to use <router-outlet></router-outlet> in your app.component.html file. See [this](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5)